# Create a user and DB with the same name in one line

Tags: shell-script, mysql

This is how I create a MySQL authorized, all privileged DB user and a corresponding DB instance with the same name, directly from Bash:

```
echo "CREATE USER "${domain}"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY \"${dbup}\";" | mysql -u root -p"${dbrp}"
echo "CREATE DATABASE ${domain};" | mysql -u root -p"${dbrp}"
echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${domain}.* TO ${domain}@localhost;" | mysql -u root -p"${dbrp}"
```

Could the first two commands merged into one command somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a "Here Document" aka [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).  e.g.:

```
cat <<EOF | mysql -u root -p"${dbrp}"
CREATE USER '${domain}'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '${dbup}';
CREATE DATABASE '${domain}';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${domain}.* TO '${domain}'@localhost;
EOF
```

Unfortunately, `mysql` still doesn't support rollback of CREATE USER or CREATE DATABASE or GRANT etc (it does an [implicit commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html) for DDL operations), otherwise I'd say you should wrap all those commands inside a transaction (so that if one fails, they all fail and everything reverts back to the way it was).

Comment: Thanks. I already tried heredocument but had problems expanding the variables inside the MySQL shell. One more thing, what I did in the end was to unite the first two sql commands into on line: `CREATE USER "${domain}"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY ${dbup};
CREATE DATABASE ${domain};`.

Comment: this does not expand *anything* inside mysql's shell.  the sh or bash or whatever shell expands it all and then pipes it into mysql.

Comment: Yes I seem to have done this with heredocument in a different way in which the variables weren't expanded.

Comment: if you put single-quotes around the heredoc marker (e.g. `<<'EOF'` instead of `<<EOF`) then shell expansion does not happen, just as if the entire heredoc was in single-quotes.

Comment: Yes I think I didn't put  these and another problem caused that (probably single quotes around the variables or I'm misrecall something.

Answer (score 3):

Why not even more simple? One not too long line is enough for all of the three tasks.

```
[root@dev2.net][~]# mysql -e'show databases' | grep test_se          # not exists yet
[root@dev2.net][~]# domain=test_se
[root@dev2.net][~]# mysql -v -e"create database ${domain};grant all on ${domain}.* to ${domain}@localhost identified by 'mysuperpassw00rd'"
--------------
create database test_se
--------------

--------------
grant all on test_se.* to test_se@localhost identified by 'mysuperpassw00rd'
--------------

[root@dev2.net][~]# mysql -e'show databases' | grep test_se           # here we are!
test_se
```

I almost never use `create user`, it is just useless from my standpoint unless you need to add the same user to many DBs. Also, concatenation with `;` as you can see works pretty well.

Remove `-v` to turn off verbose output.